# Reemplazar option de Select por Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

Buen dia, Estoy intentando reemplazar las option de cada Select por checkbox para poder darle un mejor estilo y mejorar la funcionalidad que cumple pero al cambiarlo por Checkbox no cumple la función que hace con option, Las función que cumple es la búsqueda de etiquetas seleccionadas en cada Select, Es para Blogger.

Yo busco lograr que haga la busqueda pero con varias checkbox seleccionadas en en cada Select. Pero no he tenido exito, Espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias!

```
<div class="tabs-outer">
    <div class="tabs-cap-top cap-top">
        <div class="cap-left"></div>
        <div class="cap-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fauxborder-left tabs-fauxborder-left">
        <div class="fauxborder-right tabs-fauxborder-right"></div>
        <div class="region-inner tabs-inner">
            <div class="tabs section" id="crosscol">
                <div class="widget HTML" id="HTML3">
                    <h2 class="title">Buscador Avanzado</h2>
                    <div class="widget-content">
                        <div id="multi-search">
                            <select class="cmbColumn" id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn[]" multiple>
                               <input type="Checkbox" name="cmbColumn[]" value="acción+" />1
                                <input type="Checkbox" name="cmbColumn[]" value="TV" /> TV
                                <input type="Checkbox" name="cmbColumn[]" value="TV" /> TV
                                <input type="Checkbox" name="cmbColumn[]" value="TV" /> TV
                            </select>
                            <select class="cmbSidebar" id="cmbSidebar" name="cmbSidebar[]" multiple>
<input type="checkbox" name="cmbSidebar[]" value="TV+" />1
<input type="checkbox" name="cmbSidebar[]" value="TV" /> TV
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cmbSidebar[]" value="TV" /> TV
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cmbSidebar[]" value="TV" /> TV
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cmbSidebar[]" value="TV" /> TV
                            </select>
                            <select class="cmbColor" id="cmbColor" name="cmbColor[]" multiple>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cmbColor[]" value="TV" />1
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cmbColor[]" value="TV" /> TV
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cmbColor[]" value="TV" /> TV
                      </select>
                            <input class="filtro" onclick=" getValue() " value="Filtrar" type="button" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <span class="widget-item-control">
                            <span class="item-control blog-admin">
                                <a class="quickedit" href="//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4472703516037708465&amp;widgetType=HTML&amp;widgetId=HTML3&amp;action=editWidget&amp;sectionId=crosscol" onclick=" return _WidgetManager._PopupConfig(document.getElementById(&quot;HTML3&quot;)); " target="configHTML3" title="Edit">
                                    <img alt="" src="http://img1.blogblog.com/img/icon18_wrench_allbkg.png" height="18" width="18" />
                                </a>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tabs section" id="crosscol-overflow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-cap-bottom cap-bottom">
        <div class="cap-left"></div>
        <div class="cap-right"></div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue() {
        var valcmbColumn = document.getElementById("cmbColumn").value;
        valcmbSidebar = document.getElementById("cmbSidebar").value;
        valcmbColor = document.getElementById("cmbColor").value;
        valOutput = (valcmbColumn + valcmbSidebar + valcmbColor);
        window.open("/search/label/" + valOutput, "_self");
    }

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == "block") {
            e.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            e.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script></div>
```

Comment: Antes de tratar de cambiar a `checkbox` prueba agregando corchetes a los nombres de cada select e incluir el atributo multiple, ejemplo: `<select class="cmbSidebar" id="cmbSidebar" name="cmbSidebar[]" multiple>`. Si funciona, entonces sí hay posibilidad de cambiar de `select` a `checkbox`

Comment: @Triby Lo acabo de hacer y si funciona, Como seria para el cambio?

Comment: Excelente, cambia todos los `option` por `checkbox`, cada grupo con el mismo nombre (usando corchetes) ´<input type="checkbox" name="cmbSidebar[]" value="TV"> TV´ (¿salto de línea?) ´<input type="checkbox" name="cmbSidebar[]" value="Película+"> Película´...

Comment: @Triby lo hice pero no esta cumpliendo su función, Es como si no lee los value. `<select class="cmbColumn" id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn[]" multiple> <input type="Checkbox" name="cmbColumn[]" value="TV+" />TV`

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que estás intentando. Aquí ya no debe ir el `select` solo los `checkbox`

Comment: @Triby Ya lo edite, Como quitaria los `Select` , No comprendo.